# TinyMCE - Difference in published events -- Javascript implementation and Angular wrapper 10.2.0

Tags: angular

I am trying to move a TinyMCE implementation to angular in an existing javascript application. I'm using TinyMCE EditorModule in angular, but have realized that "change" event on editor is no longer firing in the same manner.

The following code fires a 'change' event on the first character in an editor.

```
<div>
   <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
   tinymce.init({
     selector: '#mytextarea',
     setup: (editor) => {
        editor.on("change", (e) => {
           console.log("got a change");
        });
     }
   });
</script>
```

While this angular example only fires when a second NodeChange happens in the editor.  Nothing fires on first key stroke.

```
component.html
...
<editor
 [init]="{
  base_url: '/tinymce',
  setup: setup.bind(this)
 }"
 ></editor>

from the component.js
...
export class TinyMceComponent {
    setup(editor:Editor) {
        editor.on('change', (e) => {
            console.log("GOT A CHANGE");
          });
      
    }
}
```

I can't find what would make this happen.  And my code is trivial.

Thanks for any suggestions.

This code is demo code from tinymce, and is quite simple.
I've tried to look at the options that are on the editor after init, but no luck.